# My Facebook app recently stopped working when accessed from mobile devices, but desktop browsing still works

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

When accessed from mobile, my Facebook app now shows "Sorry, something went wrong ..." error message:
[image: Sorry, something went wrong.]
It worked well about a week ago. When browsing on desktop game still works well.

Facebook responds with HTTP error 500 (which is "Internal server error" HTTP error code) with such HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Error Facebook</title>
    <div class="fb_header">
      <div class="fb_logo">
        <img src="//static.facebook.com/images/mobile/chrome/ui/page-header/logo/fb_logo_small.gif" width="77" height="15" alt="Facebook" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area error">
      <strong>Sorry, something went wrong.</strong>
      <p>We are working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can.</p>
      <p><a href="/">&laquo; Back to Home</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="area footer">
      <hr />
      Facebook &copy; 2020 &#183;
      <a href="/help/">Help</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

A 500 error indicates that you have provided the server (Facebook) a valid request and it was unable to handle it. *Usually* if there something wrong on your end, the server would return 4xx response.

To investigating the issue, there are multiple things to try. Such as different browsers & mobile devices, clearing cache & cookies.

You can try re-creating the issue using a mobile emulator such as [Chrome device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode). Doing so you can check the console for errors and also compare the requests between mobile & web. You can run the different request through Postman. (Chrome device mode & Postman are just examples, there are many tools that you can use to emulate mobile browsers).

Finally as the issue is a 500 error provided by from Facebook. You can always log a ticket with them https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049

Answer (score 0):

If you have accessed your Facebook through your mobile application it might be because of the cache that you have in the application try clearing it first because sometimes the cache messes-up with the application.

I wish you tried to access the social media platform through google chrome in your mobile.

Moreover this error you are questioning is a most common issue that Facebook has been resolving for years but, still didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.try to logout from your computer

Go to your Security and Login Settings.
Go to the section Where You're Logged In. You may have to click See More to see all of the sessions where you're logged in.
Find the session you want to end. Click and then click Log Out

2.login in from your phone browser
3. change your password from the pc
4.login again